# LINQ to Dataset DBNULL problem / null reference exception

Tags: c#, linq, dbnull

I have the following LINQ query which always results in an error when my "Remark" column in dtblDetail is null, even though I test if it is NULL.

```
var varActiveAndUsedElementsWithDetails =
                        from e in dtblElements
                        join d in dtblDetails on e.PK equals d.FK into set
                        from d in set.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where (e.ElementActive == true)
                        select new
                        {
                            ElementPK = e.PK,
                            Remark = d.IsRemarkNull() ? null : d.Remark
                        };
```

The error message was:
"The value for column 'Remark' in table 'dtblDetails' is DBNull."
After adding the test for d.IsRemarkNull() a null reference exception is thrown.

Can you help me with this?

I've already checked the following websites but didn't find anything useful other than that I have to test for DBNULL. But as said this doesn't solve my problem.

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/3d124f45-62ec-4006-a5b1-ddbb578c4e4d
- http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2007/02/13/nulls-linq-to-datasets-part-3.aspx
- http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=506645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the whole 'd' item was empty.
So calling 'd.IsRemarkNull()' resulted in the null reference exception.
The following code fixed the problem:

```
var varActiveAndUsedElementsWithDetails =
                    from e in dtblElements
                    join d in dtblDetails on e.PK equals d.FK into set
                    from d in set.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where (e.ElementActive == true)
                    select new
                    {
                        ElementPK = e.PK,
                        Remark = d == null? null : (d.IsRemarkNull() ? null : d.Remark)
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the error coming from?  Is it possible that it is the d.IsRemarkNull() that is causing it?  What does that method look like?

Perhaps:

```
DBNull.Value.Equals(d.Remark)
```

Comment: The error happens as soon as I fetch the first value which contains a DBNull. So varActiveAndUsedElementsWithDetails.First() could produce it. The method d.IsRemarkNull() is auto-generated on the dataset and calls the System.Data.DataRow.IsNull() method: "return this.IsNull(this.tableDetails.RemarkColumn);"

Comment: I haven't used linq with SQL yet - but aren't null & DBNull treated separately?  Have you tried adding a where clause to explicitly filter for rows where !DBNull.Value.Equals(d.Remark)?

Comment: Yes they are treated separately, that's why you can't test d.Remark == null. However the generated method.IsRemarkNull() should exactly handle this situation, but here it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I found out that the problem was in fact a null reference exception because 'd' was null. So calling d.IsRemarkNull() resulted in this null reference exception. Thanks a lot for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this field doesn't allow null in db, get a default value for it, and avoid handling null values

Comment: Thanks for the hint but the field does allow NULL in the db. Also the typed datatable field does allow NULL. That's why it has this auto-generated d.IsRemarkNull() method btw.