# LINQ to Dataset Left Join, how to Count nulls

Tags: linq

First, take a look at this thread

[LINQ to Dataset DBNULL problem / null reference exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881225/linq-to-dataset-dbnull-problem-null-reference-exception)

The link above provides you how to LEFT JOIN and then SELECT column that have NULL value in it without taking Exception error.

My problem is I want to COUNT the column is null in WHERE clause (after my LEFT JOIN, some NULL value pop up in the column), something like this:

```
int tmp1 = 
(
from n in dt_query
join m in dt_query2 
on n.Field<string>("VC_CLIENT_MAXID") equals m.Field<string>("VC_CHAT_MAXID") into nm
from m in nm.DefaultIfEmpty()
where 
    //string.IsNullorEmpty(m.Field<string>("VC_CHAT_STAFF"))
    //DBNull.Value.Equals(m.Field<string>("VC_CHAT_STAFF"))
    //m.IsNull("VC_CHAT_STAFF")
    //object.Equals(m.Field<string>("VC_CHAT_STAFF"), xxx) <<< String xxx = null on above
    select n.Field<string>("VC_CLIENT_MAXID")
    ).Count();
```

The commented lines are the solution I tried but it didn't work for me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're asking is how to count the number of records where the joined table is null, then give this a try.

```
int tmp1 = 
    (
    from n in dt_query
    join m in dt_query2 
    on n.Field<string>("VC_CLIENT_MAXID") 
        equals m.Field<string>("VC_CHAT_MAXID") into nm

    from LeftJoinM in nm.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where 

        LeftJoinM  == null

    select n.Field<string>("VC_CLIENT_MAXID")
    ).Count();
```

If I misunderstood you, please let me know in a comment and I'll be happy to update.

Comment: This is worked for me (this time) !
But I have something to ask you.
What does "m == null" means ?
I think filter out the NULL in the specified column didn't work with this (Because I can't tell which column I checked for NULL  anyway). 
What if the table A has VC_CLIENT_MAXID to join and VC_CHAT_STAFF from table B is NULL from the start ? I think I will get wrong answer ?

Comment: I've renamed m to "LeftJoinM" to make it a little clearer.  "m == null" or now "LeftJoinM == null" basically checks to see if the join failed.  It returns all records that could NOT be joined.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VC_CLIENT 
LEFT JOIN VC_CHAT ON VC_CLIENT_MAXID = VC_CHAT_MAXID 
WHERE VC_CHAT_STAFF IS NULL
> My point is "m == null" is not the perfect answer to translate this query. As you can see, if VC_CHAT has VC_CHAT_STAFF null data in it, I can't select it out because "m == null" can provide me only rows which the join failed. Am I right ?
What will you translate this query into LINQ syntax ? because I get NullException when I tried calling "m.Field<string>("VC_CHAT_STAFF")" in WHERE clause
Anyway, thanks very much about your above answer. It helps me much !

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the following code..Hope this should work

```
int tmp1 = 
        (
        from n in dt_query
        join m in dt_query2 
        on n.Field<string>("VC_CLIENT_MAXID") 
            equals m.Field<string>("VC_CHAT_MAXID") into nm

        from temp in nm.where(t => t.Field<string>("VC_CLIENT_MAXID") ==null).DefaultIfEmpty()


        select VC_CLIENT_MAXID=  (temp== null) ? "" :n.Field<string>("VC_CLIENT_MAXID");
        ).Count();
```